# how to get the current locale in symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get the curent locale in Symfony 2.3 ?

I have a url like this:
`/{_locale}/blog/article` with FR as a default parameter.
I try the following: 
`$this->get('request')->getLocale()`

but it always give me the default parameter.And i am aware that i can use `$this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'fr');`

but the problem is that when the user first visit my website he has nothing stored in his session.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can get current locale by this

```
 $request = $this->get('request');
 echo $request->getLocale();
```

Comment: Hello, what's difference between $this->get('request')->getLocale() and $this->get('translator')->getLocale() ?

Comment: @CappY basically both will return the current locale but `get('translator')` can be used for more functionality like you can get translation for desired language by providing the locale.

Comment: what about getting it in a form type? if i try to inject the request to a form type I got an error

Comment: @petekaner you can send it from controller when you prepare your form by passing an array in form (2nd parameter)

Comment: $this->get('request') is depreciated, I suggest to use "get('translator')" now or to add Request $request as hint in your function

Comment: Hi, when we use the above code from where it is getting the locale value?

Comment: @PM-Riabel you will use this code when u need it. I did not get your actual point. What u want to say. Please give more info.

Comment: thanks for your comment. what I asked was what is the resource of `getLocale()`

Comment: Simply use `$request->getLocale();` in Symfony 4.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `$request->getLocale();` in Symfony 4 since this seems to the top link when you search in Google for this topic.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to access locale inside a service or controller you can use `@request_stack` to inject `RequestStack`.
- `RequestStack` has `getCurrentRequest()` method to get current request. Then you can use `getLocale()` to get user current locale.