# How to use KNP Translatable in a form type

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm using KNP Translatable and I have the following data structure:

User (id, name, email, password...)
Role (id, name @translatable)

User Role is a many to many relation.

I have the form type defined as this:

```
->add('roles', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'SocialCarBackendBundle:Role',
    'property' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true
])
```

And I implemented the __call method in the role entity:

```
public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        try {
            return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
        } catch (\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException $e) {
            return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation('get' . ucfirst($method), $arguments);
        }

    }
```

Now, in the twig template I can call the name property of the roles without problems and it renders it correctly.

But when trying to render the form I get this error:

> Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "getName()",
>   "name()", "isName()", "hasName()", "__get()" exist and have public
>   access in class "SocialCar\BackendBundle\Entity\Role".

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

symfony's propertyaccessor component has not magic calls enabled for EntityType property

you can see vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php to prove that.

so you have three ways(in order of complexity):

1. do getter and setters that call proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation, imho there are nothing bad using less magic things:)
2. use a more complex property like this

   'property' => 'translations[' . $options['locale'] . '].name',

   where $options['locale'] is the locale injected inside the form as an option
3. you can create a different EntityType class that extends your custom DoctrineType class that initializes PropertyAccessor to support magic calls

for more info about property accessor:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html

and about the second way:

https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/issues/67

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, looks I'm going with option 2. The only thing is I'm trying ot inject the session object to use the getLocale method but it looks like it doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: here the new way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949397/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-symfony-2-3